# Not Getting Data of MongoDB Log Appender from KAA server

Tags: mongodb, postman, kaa

I have configured my First KAA Application using Java and MongoDB Log Appenders, able to see in the KAA server DB Logs. 
But my isssue is how can i retrieve the data from MongoDB Log  Appenders to my Local system or Java system.

Tried:

I tried for Calling the POSTMAN service also but not able to find any particular API  for that.
http://10.110.25.52:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/logAppenders/536590273894852265
didn't found any API for content of LogAppneders in it.

I tried for making the database connection through Java using KAA server ip for MongoDb , but unsuccessful.
Below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);


        // if database doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
        com.mongodb.DB db = mongo.getDB("Kaa");
        System.out.println("db="+db);

        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("logs_53659027389148522657");
        System.out.println("table="+table);

        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("temperature", "30");

        DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What error message are you getting and Have you checked the document in the collection through mongo console....?

Comment: I am getting IO Exception: couldn't connect to [/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: I have checked , but my issue is more on collecting the data which is stored in KAA server of mongoDb Logs, also implemented CollectionDemo Program but not able to retrieve so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: In VM change the network type as "Bridge type" and check the ip in ubuntu by "hostname -I" ,set the particular IP to the sandbox default IP ,run your first KAA application. the logs will be generated in MongoDB Log Appender. But to connect that you need to change the Configuration file  by running this command "Vim /etc/mongod.conf" Comment out the defualt ip like this "#127.0.0.1" beacuse it can allow only localhost because of this i was not able to connect it outside VM.
After changing IP you need to again generate the SDK of your application so that it can connect to that IP , rather than "localhost".

By using roboClient you can easily connect to the mongodb database and do the Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Kaa does not provide REST API for retrieving the data added to MongoDB with Log Appender. All available REST APIs you can find in the [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/). You can connect to the MongoDB with your own application and make data retrieving.

Comment: Thanks for replying , then how we can use or retrieve the data stored in MongoDb of Kaa Server. i guess then there is no use of the data stored in it.

Comment: I found the notification demo in which we can send the notification back to the java console ,but still figuring out how to get the data from MongoDb log Appenders.